# what is that icon next to your name?

Tags: clash-of-clans

When u go to your clan and it lists the people in it some people have an icon on the left side of their name. It is the clan war icon so I know it has something to do with war but what exactly does it mean?

Comment: Which icon? There are three kind of.

Comment: also whoops this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The "Clan War" icon in the clan listing shows underneath the rank numbers for the members of the clan who would (or are) be able to participate in a Clan War.

Clan Wars always involve whole multiples of 5 players.  So for instance, if your clan has 11 members, only the top 10 (apparently ordered by trophies) would participate in a war, and they'd engage the top 10 players in the enemy clan.